# Dealing with IO action

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm a haskell beginner and got stuck with IO action behavior.

```
main() :: IO()
  retval = if something
             then "foo"
             else `return value of IO String action` i.e getLine
  print retval
```

How can I make this code work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both branches of `if` have to have the same type. Since `"foo"` is `String`, the `else` part has to be a `String` too (but not an `IO String`).

You can do

```
retval = if something
           then return "foo"
           else getLine
```

in order to make all parts of the `if` of type `IO String`. Here, `return` converts the string `"foo"` to an `IO` action which just returns `"foo"`.

Then, you need to extract the `String` back out of the `IO String` because `print` expects a string (i.e. you carry out the `IO` action):

```
retval <- if something
            then return "foo"
            else getLine
```

Comment: Thanks for kind reply :) I understand now

Answer (score 1):

Both the `then` and `else` value in an `if` need to have the same type.  You need to convert `String` to `IO String`.

The `return` function will do this for you.

```
main:: IO()
main = do
    retval <- if something
                 then return "foo"
                 else getLine
     print retval
```

Note that because the this is of type IO a, you also need to assign the value of retVal using "<-", not `let .. = ..`.